# Restore specific indexes in Elasticsearch

Tags: linux, elasticsearch

i have 2 Elasticsearch (1 for PROD and 1 for DEV Environment)
and i already set a NFS partition (repository) for backup ALL indexes from PROD through bash script.
and we have the same indexes on the DEV Elasticsearch but with different data within. and today developer said that he wants a full copy of 2 indexes from PROD to DEV. i've already have full index backup!
I Know how to restore all indexes, but how can i choose the only 2 indexes? not the full restore of indexes?
for example i have snapshot which contains this guys

```
{
   "snapshot":"elasticsearch_all_indicies_25_06_2018",
   "uuid":"aGzmhyOkmlkfmflnslndfs",
   "version_id":5060699,
   "version":"5.6.6",
   "indices":[
      "banners",
      "products",
      "catalogs",
      "darbiz",
      ".kibana",
      "invoices",
      "bundles",
      "groups",
      "searchitems",
      "params",
      "orders"
   ],
   "state":"SUCCESS",
   "start_time":"2018-06-24T23:30:01.978Z",
   "start_time_in_millis":1529883001978,
   "end_time":"2018-06-24T23:30:06.765Z",
   "end_time_in_millis":1529883006765,
   "duration_in_millis":4787,
   "failures":[

   ],
   "shards":{
      "total":75,
      "failed":0,
      "successful":75
   }
}
```

and for example i need to restore to DEV only orders and params indexes, not the whole set, how can i do that? thank you

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can specify the indices to restore in the body of the JSON content sent to the REST API.  For example:

```
POST /_snapshot/my_backup/snapshot_1/_restore
{
  "indices": "order,params",
  "ignore_unavailable": true,
  "include_global_state": true
}
```

**Reference**

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-snapshots.html#_restore